# process.env.PORT from dotenv causes EACESS: permission denied error in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I just installed dotenv in my project and I am requiring it with this code:

```
require("dotenv").config();
```

And then using my variables like so:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${process.env.ENDPOINT}:${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

In .env:

```
ENDPOINT = "127.0.0.1";
PORT = 5000;
```

Code works just fine if I add the variables as constants within my js file, but when I try to access the variables through process.env I get:

> events.js:291
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^
>
> Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 5000;
> at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1299:21)
> at listenInCluster (net.js:1364:12)
> at Server.listen (net.js:1461:5)
> at Function.listen (C:\Users\Darkbound\Desktop\TouchScreenProject\SmartFactory\server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
> at Object. (C:\Users\Darkbound\Desktop\TouchScreenProject\SmartFactory\server\main.js:34:5)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:14)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
> at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
> at emitErrorNT (net.js:1343:8)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {       code: 'EACCES',
> errno: -4092,   syscall: 'listen',   address: '5000;',   port: -1 }

I have tried using other ports, I get the same error on all ports, I have tried 3000, 3010, 5000 etc.

If the other variable, `ENDPOINT` is accesses without problems, so if I do:

```
const PORT = 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${process.env.ENDPOINT}:${PORT}`);
});
```

This works.

**EDIT SOLVED:** I found the issue, as usual, right after I ask the question. The issue is that I have `;` at the end of each variable in the .env file. this happened because I copy/pasted the variable from my javascript and I only deleted the `const` but forgot about `;`

Comment: yes, `.env` file does not accept `;`

Comment: I add same like ; in .env file after remove issue resolve thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting this, saved my time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the issue, as usual, right after I ask the question. The issue is that I have `;` at the end of each variable in the `.env` file. this happened because I copy/pasted the variable from my javascript and I only deleted the `const` but forgot about `;`

Answer (score 0):

just remove `;` from `.env` file when declare PORT.

`PORT=5000; ==> PORT = 5000`